# Rerender MathJax text?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have a web app running on Apache that has a text input box. Here the users can publish text and preview it. I have been able to dynamically render mathematical formulas using MathJax in the preview. The issue is after a uploads the HTML code (their publish text) to the MySQL server and then when any user visits that site, the MathJax does not render. I save the exact same HTML code that is generated after the user making some text italic, render mathematical formulas, etc. So the saved HTML does not contain "x^2" but rather the code generated by MathJax to actually view the maths correctly.

How do I go from the "raw" HTML code and render the math jax tags and code that is inside a `<div class="text-post">`? It is there, it just does not render anything, just some blank square that is taking up space.

I have tried using `MathJax.rerender();` using `window.onload() { ... }` so that the MathJax renders when the page renders. I have also tried `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);` as well as `MathJax.typeset();`
All of these are placed at the end of `window.onload { ...  [code] }`.

Edit: I am using MathJax 3.x, I have seen some people commenting on other posts that the notation is changed from MathJax 2.x however searching in their documentation for the keyword "Rerender" gives only one, very useless comment about returning false when calling rerender and not how to actually rerender equations.

Comment: Please provide a code sample that shows either how you save the rendering or how/what you inject it. A random guess would be that you're using the SVG output with its default "font-caching" behavior and are not storing the SVG paths that are separtely in the DOM.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger It takes the text (`document.getElementById('input').innerHTML`), enters it into an output div and calls `MathJax.typeset();`. It generates MathJax specific tags that for obvious reasons (they are not put through a renderer) are not rendered again because when I visit the post there is no `$5x+x^2$` only the MathJax tags. How do I re-render MathJax tags is my question.

Comment: @linker Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `MathJax.typeset()` in the `window.onload()` event, call `MathJax.typeset()` when the entire **document** has loaded.

For example:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(){
    MathJax.typeset()
})
```

Comment: This does not re-render the math.

Comment: @linker Sorry, I am not sure I understood your problem correctly. Is the raw HTML of the format `\(x^2\)` or `x^2`? If it is the latter, are you trying to figure out how to change it to the former?

Comment: I am rendering the html tags that is generated from MathJax.typeset(). Its multiple tags, with different layers and references. Try to genereate x^2 using mathjax and then inspect the element in your browser, looking at the generated html/js code. That is what I am trying to re-render